# React Form onSubmit not firing within functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a form within a functional component called Payment. However when submitting the form by clicking the button the handler handleSubmitPayment(e) doesn't get called. Nor is there any error message in the console.

```
function Payment() {

  function handleSubmitPayment(e) {
    console.log("Form Submitted");
    console.log(e);
  }


  return (
  ...
  <form onSubmit={(e) => {console.log(e); handleSubmitPayment(e); /*e.preventDefault();*/}}>
  <Row>
      <Col>
        <span className="payment_form_text">CC Number</span>
        <input id="ccnumb" value=""/>
      </Col>
  </Row>
  <Row>
      <Col xs={6}>
       <span className="payment_form_text">CC Exp</span>
       <input id="ccexp" value=""/>
      </Col>
      <Col xs={6}>
          <span className="payment_form_text">CVV</span>
          <input id="cvv" value=""/>
      </Col>
  </Row>
     <Button variant="success" id="payButton" type="submit" style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
       Pay
     </Button>
 </form>
...
)
}

export default Payment;
```

Please note these are dummy fields and I am not using a basic form to send raw payment data.

What could be a possible reason for this? Or what code changes do I need to deploy to make this work?

I can answer any more questions or provide more details if needed!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? Have you tried using `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behavior of `submit` event? I think you are guessing that `handleSubmitPayment` function is not called because you don't see the log statements. Unless you preserve the logs in browser dev tools, logs will be cleared when the browser window reloads on form submission.

Comment: >  logs will be cleared when the browser window reloads on form submission

Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Any output on the console will be cleared as soon as the browser window is reloaded which is what will happen on form submission if you don't stop the default behavior of `submit` event using `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting what you're asking for here but I believe [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/e58qk) is what you want? All I did was add `e.preventDefault()` to the `handleSubmitPayment` function and then in onSubmit I called

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmitPayment(e)}>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want. It seems that it doesn't work within my code though. I am using the Chrome console to check if it is fired

Comment: Can I get a little more context with your code. It might be logging it somewhere else and that's why it doesn't seem like its working?